# What is the possible reason that my R squared value equal to 1

Tags: cross-validation, r-squared, weka, bioinformatics

I have one natural data set of biological data from my lab such as binding energy, exon type and oligo length etc. And my goal is to train a model to predict skipping rate. I used weka with no filter on my data and set the number of fold for cross-validation to be 10. (I have 515 instances in total) I used the greedy option of funciton `LinearRegression`. My summary gave me a model to predict the skipping rate with exon type ignored and meanwhile got perfect R^2 = 1 and F-stat equals infinity. I don't trust this results and I want to prove it's invalid. However, even if I manually divide my data into training and testing data sets with 2/3 portion, shuffling both of them and run classification with the same `LinearRegression` evaluation function, I still got R^2 = 1 and F-stat equals infinity. What could go wrong in my analysis?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you plot the predicted vs real skipping rate  for your data with the model that gives R^2? What is the formula? Is it predicting perfectly? Are you sure you haven't given the skipping rate as a predictor to the regression?

Comment: @highBandWidth I'm sure I haven't given the skipping rate as a predictor.

Comment: @highBandWidth I've updated my case.

Comment: Where does your data come from? Could whatever software/machine which outputs your data simply calculate skipping rate as .5092 * distance from acceptor - 4.0669 dG50 etc...?

Comment: Can you also plot the predicted vs. real? Do you get the same coefficients for different random selections of the training set?

Comment: R^2 = 1 means you have a perfect fit of your data from a simple linear model. It's really hard to tell what's going on here without being familiar with your data. But from the output, it looks like your trying to *predict* a *predicted value*. If I'm understanding this correctly it sounds like you have a model that's modelling a modeled value. As long as the same model was used in both cases, that it would result in a perfect fit is clear.

Comment: @CliffAB I think your explanation make sense

Answer (score 1):

> R^2 = 1 means you have a perfect fit of your data from a simple linear model. It's really hard to tell what's going on here without being familiar with your data. But from the output, it looks like your trying to predict a predicted value. If I'm understanding this correctly it sounds like you have a model that's modelling a modeled value. As long as the same model was used in both cases, that it would result in a perfect fit is clear.

Comment: I've copied this comment by @CliffAB as a community wiki answer because the comment is, more or less, an answer to this question. We have a dramatic gap between answers and questions. At least part of the problem is that some questions are answered in comments: if comments which answered the question were answers instead, we would have fewer unanswered questions.